# Preserve axis settings between FuncAnimation frames

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I want to generate a video of an animated series of line plots from different files.
Below is the start for my python code.
I am using the [matplotlib.animation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.Animation)
library.

It looks like this:

[image: three different line plots on top of each other]

How can I erase the previous plots (show one line at a time),
but keep the same axes and plot size?

If I call [`plt.clf()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clf),
it resets the axes.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def plot_initialize():
    plt.xlim(0, 6)
    plt.ylim(0, 35)
    plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 35])

def plot_figure(filepath):
    print(filepath)
    columns = np.loadtxt(filepath, unpack=True)
    x = columns[0]
    y = columns[1]
    plt.plot(x, y, color="blue", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import tempfile
    myfile1 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    myfile1.write('# myfile1\n1  2\n2  4\n3  6\n4  8\n5 10\n')
    myfile1.seek(0)

    myfile2 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    myfile2.write('# myfile2\n1  1\n2  4\n3  9\n4 16\n5 25\n')
    myfile2.seek(0)

    myfile3 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    myfile3.write('# myfile3\n1  2\n2  4\n3  8\n4 16\n5 32\n')
    myfile3.seek(0)

    filepaths = [myfile1.name, myfile2.name, myfile3.name]

    my_figure = plt.figure()
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(my_figure, plot_figure, init_func=plot_initialize, frames=filepaths, interval=500, repeat=False)
    anim.save("out.mp4")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might make sense to only update the data in the animation and not create new plots every time

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def plot_initialize():
    return 

def plot_figure(filepath):
    print(filepath)
    columns = np.loadtxt(filepath, unpack=True)
    x = columns[0]
    y = columns[1]
    line.set_data(x,y)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import tempfile
    myfile1 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    myfile1.write('# myfile1\n1  2\n2  4\n3  6\n4  8\n5 10\n')
    myfile1.seek(0)

    myfile2 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    myfile2.write('# myfile2\n1  1\n2  4\n3  9\n4 16\n5 25\n')
    myfile2.seek(0)

    myfile3 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    myfile3.write('# myfile3\n1  2\n2  4\n3  8\n4 16\n5 32\n')
    myfile3.seek(0)

    filepaths = [myfile1.name, myfile2.name, myfile3.name]

    my_figure = plt.figure()
    plt.xlim(0, 6)
    plt.ylim(0, 35)
    plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 35])
    line, = plt.plot([], [], color="blue", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(my_figure, plot_figure, init_func=plot_initialize, frames=filepaths, interval=500, repeat=False)
    anim.save("out.mp4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `plt.clf()`and `plot_initialize()` in `plot_figure()` works:

```
def plot_figure(filepath):
    print(filepath)
    columns = np.loadtxt(filepath, unpack=True)
    x = columns[0]
    y = columns[1]
    plt.clf()
    plot_initialize()
    plt.plot(x, y, color="blue", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")
```

Result:

[image]